# Is there a way to make the 'One' table optional in OneToManyRelationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-many, database-relations

I have two tables, one is Anonym the other is Userdatabase. I want my app to work without requiring any login info therefore it will work with Anonym only by using the deviceid of the user to process account information. If however, a user wants to access extra features they need to create a user with username/password. Then I will process the data using Userdatabase table. A user can have multiple devices so there is a OneToMany relationship in there, but a device doesn't have to have a User (they don't need to register) which breaks the relationship. Is there a way to make the Userdatabase table optional while keeping the OneToMany relationship? Perhaps by inserting a method or another class within UserDatabase? Please find the code below:

--Models--

```
class Anonym(models.Model):
    deviceid=models.ForeignKey(Userdatabase,max_length=200,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    accounttype=models.TextField(default='Free')
    numberofattempts=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Userdatabase(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    deviceid=models.TextField(default='inputdeviceid')
    accounttype=models.TextField(default='Free')
    numberofattempts=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

--urls--

```
urlpatterns=[path('deviceregister/<str:id>/',views.deviceregistration)]
```

--views--

```
def deviceregistration(request,id):
    import time

    deviceid=id
    newdevice-models.Anonym(created=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),deviceid=deviceid)
    newdevice.save()

    return HttpResponse('Succesful registration')
```

When I send a request as '/deviceregister/123456/' for example, django raises an ValueError saying Cannot assign "'123456'": "Anonym.deviceid" must be a "Userdatabase" instance.

Answer (score 0):

you should search by fieldname, which contains id. in your case it is `deviceid_id`.

```
newdevice=models.Anonym(created=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),deviceid_id=deviceid)
```

`deviceid` in your case should be `Userdatabase.objects.get(pk=id)`

```
deviceid=Userdatabase.objects.get(pk=id)
newdevice=models.Anonym(created=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),deviceid=deviceid)
```

in my opinion - field names in your project really can confuse anyone

Comment: But Userdatabase.objects.get(pk=id) does not exist at this point. I’m only registering by deviceid, there is nothing in userdatabase to find. This will just raise an error

Comment: if you don't have Userdatabase.object - you can not create relation Anonym.deviceid=models.ForeignKey(Userdatabase) to this object. It is not exists. Thats why you can use models.Anonym(deviceid_id=deviceid). But if it not exists, you can not be shure, that you create Userdatabase.object with this id. id is autofield, id can be other. You should before create Userdatabase.object, after it you can create  Anonym with deviceid=created_Userdatabase_object

Comment: what I am trying to say is, Userdatabase is a model and exists but an instance of it does not exists while doing the registry via deviceid. If I have the user in Userdatabase then say binding them with ForeignKey works that I know. Problem is, I do not want this relation all the time. I want to make the relation optional, so I won't have to get Userdatabase.object when I am registering the deviceid to Anonym. I hope the issue is a bit more clear now

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your model, you can just link any newly-added device to a `dummy` user. When later a user want to link a device, replace `dummy` with the real user.

If you can change your model, you can remove the foreign key relationship, and add another table which links the id of both side: one field for `deviceid` and the other `userid`.

I know both options kind of smell, but at least they should work :)

Comment: dummy might work yes. I also thought about changing the model, breaking the relationship. Just setting up indexes in both models for fast search when looking into one table, then registering for example deviceid1 to userid1. I’m not the expert on performance. Which one would serve faster, using indexes in two tables or setting up a third table between them

Comment: Not an expert either. If most of the devices are unlinked/anonymous, then a third table can save you some space, since it will only have an entry when a device is linked. For the same reason it may save you some time whenever a new device is added since we won’t have an index for the FK. If most of the devices are linked to a real user, two tables should be more efficient than three (?) intuitively. Maybe generate some data and do some measurements

Comment: I’ve decided to separate the tables for the time being. Gonna try that way, seems much simpler to handle the data